# Is SuperSLiM for Android available as Library with Eclipse?

Tags: android, superslim

I am wondering, whether [SuperSLiM](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM) is available as a library anywhere?

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this what you are looking for

https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM

Download the zip from the link on the bottom left and add it to your workspace following the steps from the link below

http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject

Hope this helps!

It is because you don't have the dependency specified in `build.gradle` One solution is to add `apply plugin: "eclipse"` in your build.gradle file and run the following

```
cd myProject/
gradle eclipse
```

Comment: Right. Perhaps I am too stupid, but how to get it as library into Eclipse?

Comment: Does not work, After import and adding appcompat libarary, it thorws an error: `No resource identifier found for attribute 'slm_headerDisplay' in package 'com.tonicartos.superslimexample'`

Comment: I don't use gradle with eclipse. So, there is no jar available to just drop  it into my project?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using maven, you should be set to go just by including the project as a dependency as usual.

Otherwise, you can get the aar from the [maven repository](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/tonicartos/superslim/) and process it into a jar. I haven't done this myself, but here is a somewhat dated [blog post about it](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/07/03/consuming-aars-eclipse.html).

Answer (score 0):

Download the Library (Zip file) from [enter link description here](https://github.com/TonicArtos/SuperSLiM)

Then import the library project to your eclipse

Copy the folder com inside the java folder to the src folder.

Clean >> Build